# Program type already present multidex error

Tags: android, gradle

We have the following setup:

App > Framework A > Framework B
The App uses A and B. Framework A only uses B.

The frameworks are build separately and served via a private maven repository.

We now did a whole lot of refactoring to Framework B, including switching from gson to moshi.

When build the app now, we get the following error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: moe.banana.jsonapi2.JsonApiConverterFactory$MoshiResponseBodyConverter","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForApi18DevelopmentDebug FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: ...
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
```

The dependencies of framework B are rather "boring":

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.2'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.6.0"

    implementation 'moe.banana:moshi-jsonapi:3.5.0'
    implementation 'moe.banana:moshi-jsonapi-retrofit-converter:3.5.0'

    // optional, for retrofit
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1"
}
```

For Framework A it is:

```
dependencies {
    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$ktx_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$play_services_version"
    implementation "FrameworkB"
}
```

As soon as we now include framework A into the app, the said exception is thrown.

#### Things we already tried

- `$ ./gradlew app:dependencies` -> There is only ONE entry of the jsonapi2 library. Everything looks correct.
- Tried to build with multidex disabled: Same error
- Include both frameworks as source modules into the app: Everything works without changing dependencies.

After trying for days now resolving this error, we came to a point where we have no idea on how to further trace this down.

Is there an other way to see where gradle thinks this duplicate class / dependency comes from?